# A simpler way to do something for the 1st item of A in C that is also in B without iterating twice

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, any

I have constructed the following script in Python 3 that does what it needs to, but, it iterates through my items twice.  Is there are way to the same outcome with a single iteration?

```
if any(A in B for A in C):
    for A in C:
        if A in B:
            # Do something with A.
            # Order of iteration is important.
            break
else:
    # Do something else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way would probably to get A in a single iteration at the C-level (using `filter` and `next`) and then use it straight away.

```
A = next(filter(B.__contains__, C), None)

if A is not None:
    # Do something with A
else:
    # Do something else
```

Comment: I don't know how to measure the speed properly, but, it does appear faster for my dataset.

Comment: It's about the fastest you can get using the standard library (it stays in C code and doesn't run any python). You may test it using `py -m timeit`

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops can also have `else` clauses, which they enter if you don't `break` out of them.  So your loop can be written

```
for A in C:
    if A in B:
        # Do something
        break
else:
    # Do something else
```

Comment: In my specific case, B is a string and A is a possible substring of B.  C is a list of strings (the keys of a dictionary).

Comment: I tested this solution and it does everything I asked for.  It is very easy to read.  The solution by Bharel is not as easy to read (perhaps not as pythonic), but, is faster for my dataset.